# ngModel doesnt´t work fine with select tag and Class instances in Angulardart 5

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In a `select` tag, I need two-way binding, but is not working.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

- `selectedCountry` is a `Country` instance: `selectedCountry.id = 3`
- `countries` is a `Country` instance List: `country1.id = 1,  country3.id = 3, country3.id = 3`

`selectedCountry` and `country3` have equal values but they aren't the same instance. Then `country3` option is not selected.

I have overwritten the equality (==) operator and `hashCode` for the `Country` class, but it still does not work.

What's the problem? Is there something similar to the angular `compareWith` directive?

```
<select [compareWith]="equals"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
   <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
      {{country.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

```
equals(o1: Country, o2: Country) {
   return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"` sounds wrong. There can only be one value be selected. What type is `selectedCountries` and what value does it contain? What does "doesnt´t work fine" mean exactly?

Comment: Instead of implementing `operator==` (which is usually a good idea anyway) you can also use https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

Comment: selectedCountry is a class instance and countries list has a class instance with equals property values, but no option is selected.

Comment: Try `trackBy`. I haven't found anything about `compareWith`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: compareWith directive is not a core angular directive: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349

Comment: So what is it then?

Comment: I need set the option with equals selectedCountry property values (identical id) as selected

Comment: My question was about `[compareWith]` that you are using and that doesn't seem to be supported by Angular. Why do you think it is? Have you tried `trackBy`?

Comment: Sorry, my failure. I rewritted the question to avoid misunderstandings

Answer (score 0):

Is there something similar to the angular compareWith directive?

You can use `trackBy` https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

```
Object trackByCountryId(_, dynamic o) => o is Country ? o.id : o;
```

```
<select *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackByCountryId" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
    {{country.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is useful when the list of countries is changing but it does not solve my problem

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. That exactly to solve the issue your question is about. I don't know what you mean with "when the list of countries is changing". I don't see that related.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

The use of the identical() function to compare values in select_control_value_accessor of the select ngModel instead ==.

I opened a github issue:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1659

Meanwhile, I'm not using two-way binding complex object:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountryId">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country.id">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```